# Why creating a native app using AWS amplify the command `amplify init` gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Tried running both from CLI and Amplify studio UI console

From CLI it gives below error -

```
[![mloya@Maheshs-MacBook-Pro mahesh-authentication-lambdas % amplify init     

Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your 
      app directory
      ? Enter a name for the project maheshauthentication
      The following configuration will be applied:][1]][1]


Project information
| Name: maheshauthentication
| Environment: dev
| Default editor: Visual Studio Code
| App type: javascript
| Javascript framework: none
| Source Directory Path: src
| Distribution Directory Path: dist
| Build Command: npm run-script build
| Start Command: npm run-script start


? Initialize the project with the above configuration? Yes
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile

For more information on AWS Profiles, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

? Please choose the profile you want to use default
 We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative.
```

From UI it gived below error -

[image]

I have checked about IAM roles and permission, can confirm the roles and permision are all given as required, also the quota limit is not exhausted. Also tried with Admin Role and with new AWS account having no quota exhausted at all.

P.S : I am able to access and work with other services, like S3 ls etc from cli.

Comment: What can you see in the logs folder in the amplify directory? Can you please share?

Answer (score -2):

As the message suggests, you do not have any AWS profiles set locally. Try running these,

1. Install aws cli if not already done.
2. run 'aws configure' and follow the instructions

Comment: I dont think the message suggest any of this sort "As the message suggests, you do not have any AWS profiles set locally". I am already able to access other services like S3 etc though. And Why is that failing from UI then?